# How do I clone a game CD- or DVD-rom that gives IO-errors whenever I try to clone it, but I can access the files just fine?

Tags: backup, dvd, clone, archiving, compact-disc

**EDIT:** I managed to do it with Gnome Disk Utils, as it just replaces unreadable bytes with 0s

*I am trying to make a backup of all my old CD- and DVD-rom games so that I can access them from anywhere and so I still have them if they break. I also want to archive them because some of them are games that I don't think were very popular so I don't think they're very likely to have files online already.
I managed to copy almost all of the games on Windows 10 using WinImage and AnyBurn, but there were a few games that stayed on 0% longer than usual and then said that it couldn't finish because of an IO-error and it said something about a problem with Cyclic Redundancy Check. I found out that I could just copy the files from the discs and then make my own ISO file using them,  but I noticed that it couldn't see the Macintosh files so I only have a backup of the Windows files. I have tried using linux and DD and DDrescue but neither of them work either.
How can the discs and the games work when I just play them, but they don't work when I clone them? Is it some sort of DRM? Why can't I just copy it with the errors and let it be, since the discs work for what I need them for??*

Comment: See [Wikipedia - List of Compact Disc and DVD copy protection schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Compact_Disc_and_DVD_copy_protection_schemes) for 50 ways this won't work with a simple copier. Also https://www.gamecopyworld.com/games/gcw_cd-backup.shtml

Comment: Back in the day, I used cloneCD and cloneDVD.